# Why does the following code segment not output 9 and output 0 two times?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm new to the concept of recursion and my understanding of it is that as it goes through the method, it builds the stack until the base case is met. That being said when mystery(9), I thought it would output

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

but instead outputted

```
0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.
```

My question is why didn't 9 get outputted if the stack was supposed to include mystery(9) and why/how does it output 0 more than once? Wouldn't the condition be false when n = 0?

```
public static void mystery(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        n--;
        mystery(n);
    }
    System.out.print(n + " ");
}
```

Comment: I would suggest running this through the debugger to see what's going on "under the hood" so to speak, or doing it on paper

Comment: Try replacing `n--; mystery(n);` with `mystery(n-1);`

Comment: @Andreas I did and it outputs what I predicted. My question is how does n--; differ from mystery(n-1); Isn't it just doing the same thing?

Comment: @GBlodgett I hand-traced it on paper, but I must have done it wrong because I got the wrong output. I just don't know why it's wrong. What's so special about n--;? in contrast to mystery(n-1)?

Comment: 1) mystery(9) -> if  statement checks 9 > 0 true 
then n--; means now n = 8, stack.push(8)
2) mystery(8) -> if statement checks 8 > 0 true
then n--; n = 7, stack.push(7)
...
9) mystery(1) -> 1 greater then 0, n-- gives us 0 then stack.push(0) 
10) mystery(0), when n = 0 if statement returns false 0 > 0
then it will print out 0, 
after that as you said it will print all values saved into stack 
stack=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Answer (score 3):

> My question is why didn't 9 get outputted if the stack was supposed to include mystery(9) and why/how does it output 0 more than once?

It is logical to see that `n` approaches zero. However recursion stops when `n =< 0`. So let's skip all the recursive calls until `n==1`.

`n` is more than zero so it gets decrements. `n == 0`. The next call, `n` is not more than zero, so recursion stops and `n` is printed out.

```
0
```

Then the last call comes off the stack. Remember you decremented `n` before the call, so it is `0` too.

```
0 0
```

Then all the other calls keep coming off the stack in the same fashion:

```
0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

`9` is never printed because you subtract from `n` before the recursive call.

---

The difference between:

```
n--;
```

And

```
mystery(n-1);
```

Is that you are decreasing `n` *before* you pass it to the function. In

```
mystery(n -1);
```

When the current call of `mystery` goes onto the stack `n` is still what it was when it was passed in. Or in the example of `9`:

```
if (n > 0) {
    //n is not changed here. It is still 9
    mystery(n -1); //Passes 8 to mystery
}
System.out.print(n + " ");
```

So when it eventually comes off the stack and hits the print statement:

```
System.out.print(n + " ");
//n is still 9, so it will print 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in `n--`.

#### Why?

Let's try `mystery(1)` as a basic explanation.

```
mystery(1) {
    if (1 > 0) {
        1--;
        mystery(0);
    }
    System.out.print(0 + " ");
}
```

You see **why** now?

---

You **CAN NOT** modify the **`n`** expecting it will stay the same.

Try to replace it with:

```
public static void mystery(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        mystery(n - 1); //minusByOne and pass it to the next call
    }
    System.out.print(n + " "); // n itself stays the same
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `n--` is equal to `n=n-1`. The difference between `n--` and `n-1` is the former update its value back to same reference `n`, the latter return a new int.

Back to your first half of the question, **why 9 is not outputted?**
Because for any n > 0 if will be (1) subtracted by 1, (2)do some recursion , (3) print it, therefore the printed value must be smaller than the input n by 1.

**Why 0 printed 2 times?**
lets break the problem and let `n` be 1:

(1) subtracted `n` by 1
`n`  become 0

(2) do some recursion
in the recursion 0 will not be subtracted again, but it will still be printed. this is the first 0 in the console

(3) print `n` from (1)
print the second 0